# React Native MQTT.js : can I select TPC/IP protocol?

Tags: react-native, tcp, mqtt

I work on a React Native app which use [MQTT.js](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js). I wanted to know if I can change the protocol ? The default is WebSockets but I would like a TCP/IP protocol.

I try this :

```
let client = mqtt.connect({
  servers: [{ host: '192.168.1.22', port: '8883' }],
  protocol: 'tcp',
  username: 'admin',
  password: 'admin'
})
```

But when I print `client` it returns :

```
{ options:
    { servers: [...],
      protocol: 'ws',
      username: 'admin',
      password: 'admin',
      defaultProtocol: 'ws',
      [...]
    }
}
```

MQTT.js support other protocols than WebSockets ? If yes, how I select them ?

Comment: try `mqtt` rather than `tcp`

Comment: Also the test to add anything but `ws` or `wss` is here: https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/blob/master/lib/connect/index.js

Comment: I changed for `mqtt` but the protocol stay `ws`. I have read the [index.js](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/blob/master/lib/connect/index.js) but it doesn't give me any more information.
The [README](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js#mqttclientstreambuilder-options) say : `The Client class wraps a client connection to an MQTT broker over an arbitrary transport method (TCP, TLS, WebSocket, ecc).` but doesn't say how to change transport method..

Comment: That statement is for the whole library, it is limited by the environment the library is run in.

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify this, since you are only passing in a single broker, you can pass is full URI rather than an array.

```
let client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://192.168.1.22:1883', {username: 'admin', password: 'admin'});
```

if you want to use the array syntax then it should look like this:

```
let client = mqtt.connect({
  servers: [
    {host: '192.168.1.22', port: 1883, protocol: 'mqtt'}
  ],
  username: 'admin',
  password: 'admin'
});
```

But the bit I pointed you at in the MQTT source is how it checks which protocols it will support. If `process.title` is equal to `browser` then it will not be able to use anything other than Websockets (ignore the `wx://` and `ali://`).

So add a `console.log(process.title)` to the start of your app to see if that test is being met.

Comment: `console.log(process.title)` return `browser`. But I run the app in a android device, I don't understand

Comment: Then you can only use MQTT over Websockets if you want to use this library.